# Getting __pthread_tpp_change_priority: Assertion error in a specific case

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have been seeing this error which I can't seem to decipher which potentially seems to be related to pthread mutex.

What I am doing is creating a FIFO for each thread and once it's created, I unblock the respective thread. I'm using a `threadWakeupIdx` flag to do so.

Everything seems to work as expected when I have 3 indexes defined in `WakeUpThreadIdx` ENUM BUT when I have 4 (i.e `NUM_ACTIVE_THREADS` = 4), I get the following error which I'm unable to decipher...

```
tpp.c:84: __pthread_tpp_change_priority: Assertion `new_prio == -1 || (new_prio >= fifo_min_prio && new_prio <= fifo_max_prio)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

```
// threads.c
void *t1(void *args)
{

    // block till the fifo for T1 thread is created
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while(threadWakeupIdx >= (T1_IDX + 1))
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    
    // ...
}

void *t2(void *args)
{

    // block till the fifo for T2 thread is created
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while(threadWakeupIdx >= (T2_IDX + 1))
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); 
    
    // ...
}

void *t3(void *args)
{

    // block till the fifo for T3 thread is created
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while(threadWakeupIdx >= (T3_IDX + 1))
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    
    // ...
}

void *t4(void *args)
{

    // block till the fifo for T4 thread is created
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while(threadWakeupIdx >= (T4_IDX + 1))
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    
    // ...
}

// main.h
typedef enum
{
    T1_INDEX = 0,
    T2_INDEX,
    T3_INDEX,
    T4_INDEX,
    NUM_ACTIVE_THREADS
} WakeUpThreadIdx;

typedef struct
{
    char fifoPath[100];        
    int fd;
} FifoInfo;

#define FIFO_REF_PATH     "/tmp"

// main.c
int threadWakeupIdx = 0;
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

static const char *threadNameList[NUM_ACTIVE_THREADS] = {T1_FIFO_NAME, T2_FIFO_NAME, T3_FIFO_NAME, T4_FIFO_NAME};

static pthread_t t1Handler;
static pthread_t t2Handler;
static pthread_t t3Handler;
static pthread_t t4Handler;

// init fifo for each thread
void InitFifo(FifoInfo *fifoList)
{
    char fifoPath[100] = {0};
    for (int idx = T1_INDEX; idx < NUM_ACTIVE_THREADS; idx++)
    {
        strcpy(fifoPath, FIFO_REF_PATH);
        strcat(fifoPath, threadNameList[idx]);
        strcpy(fifoList[idx].fifoPath, fifoPath);
        
        // create fifo ...

        // wake up a respective thread once the fifo is init'd
       pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
       threadWakeupIdx++;
       pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

       memset(fifoPath, 0, sizeof(fifoPath));
    }
    
}

int main() 
{
    FifoInfo fifoList[NUM_ACTIVE_THREADS] = {0};
    InitFifo(fifoList);

    pthread_create(&t1Handler, NULL, t1, <argument>);
    pthread_create(&t2Handler, NULL, t2, <argument>);
    pthread_create(&t3Handler, NULL, t3, <argument>);
    pthread_create(&t4Handler, NULL, t4, <argument>);
    
    pthread_join(t1Handler, 0);
    pthread_join(t2Handler, 0);
    pthread_join(t3Handler, 0);
    pthread_join(t4Handler, 0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

Been trying out different things, and noticed that if I comment out, say `pthread_create(&t3Handler, NULL, t3, <argument>);`, I don't see the error. Possibly similar to the case of having 3 `WakeUpThreadIdx` ENUM indexes.

How come is trying to create/run an extra thread causing this issue?

Comment: Why can you not create the fifo objects before creating the threads?  You can pass a fifo into the thread func in the argument - you may then only need one thread function.  You are making things avoidably difficult and complex:(

Comment: yeah I could look into that but also wanna figure out what really is causing this issue...

Comment: Who cares,if you can design it away?  Life is too short for over-complex code, especially when multithreading.  KISS for the win:)

Comment: Is there any part of your code that tries to change a thread’s priority (or perhaps a library you are using that might try it?  The assertion failure looks like someone is trying to switch to a thread-priority value that is not supported.

Comment: @MartinJames those who find ways to avoid faults without ever understanding the underlying problem, are doomed to keep on finding new entry conditions for the still-unfixed problem.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner not i'm not explicitly changing any priority myself. what I do notice is the last thing that runs before this error shows up is mapping a shared memory via `mmap()` in `main` (not shown here cause I thought it wouldn't be relevant). What I'm most concerned about is the same program running fine with 3 indices and as soon as I enter one extra, it errors out...

Comment: My wild guess would be undefined behavior, perhaps triggered by using an invalid array index.  Running the program under valgrind (or similar) might point you closer to the root of the problem.

Comment: i'm using an ARM mcu and currently don't have valgrind already built ready to be used. I tried using `-Warray-bounds` flag in Makefile and it shows no warnings.

Comment: I also removed `InitFifo ` and placed it in `main` and tried putting`while(1)` before creating any threads, I don't see the issue and as soon as I create/run threads, I do see...

Comment: An assertion failure *should* indicate a bug in the library, though in practice, it *might* indicate a usage error.

Comment: But again I can’t figure out what this error may even point to…